# Does the grandfather make a blessing on seeing his granddaughter for the first time?

Tags: blessing, pregnancy-birth, family-members

[The father of a new girl makes the shehechiyanu blessing on seeing his daughter for the first time.](/q/6676)

Does the grandfather make a beracha ? He has not seen the child before and is surely joyful. (See OC 223 (1) MB [2].)

Comment: Just FWIW, that ruling of the Mishna Berura is considered rather controversial.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you. Are there sources for those who hold this ruling is controversial?

Comment: Here's one to start http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1885&pgnum=42 (I understand Rs YS Elyashiv, SZ Auerbach, YY Fisher, M Shternbuch all rule against the MB.) IMHO the MB's opinion only has caught on because 1) poskim are embarrassed to not have anything to say for a girl 2) the MB is a big enough name that they're willing to let their own arguments slide 3) it's probably not levatala because hearing about it is good news. (You have to also wonder why not to say Shehechiyanu when first seeing a newborn son.)

Answer (score 3):

Rav Mutzafi rules that the grandparents make the blessing of "hatov vehametiv". This bracha is said when joy or something good is shared by several people.
 לכבוד הרב מוצפי שליט"א
האם צריך לברך ברכת שהחיינו על נכד או נכדה חדשה במיוחד המדובר בנכד/ה ראשונים שהופכים אותנו לסבא וסבתא תודה
תשובה
לא ברכת שהחיינו, אלא כמה מהפוסקים כתבו לברך ברכת הטוב והמטיב, כיון שזו שמחה משותפת. ושהחיינו מברכים לאדם פרטי דוקא. 
From here:
http://www.doresh-tzion.co.il/QAShowAnswer.aspx?qaid=111426

Rav Nissim Karelitz, Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach, and Rav Chaim Kanievsky, hold that no brocho is recited by the grandparents.
The Mishna Brura's ruling is not accepted by many today, and even the parents don't make a shecheyanu.

תשובת הרב שמואל ברוך גנוט:
הוראת רבי ניסים קרליץ, רבי שלמה זלמן אוירבך ורבי חיים קניבסקי, הברכה היא רק להורים ולא לסבים ולסבתות, כיון שגם על עצם חידושו של המשנה ברורה לברך ברכת שהחיינו על לידת בת, ישנם רבים שחולקים, ולכן אין להוסיף שגם יתר בני המשפחה יברכו.
From here:
http://www.shabes.net/bsd/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=135%3Ahalachaquestions&id=3300%3Abracha-nechda&Itemid=124

Comment: Is R Mutzafi coming from the Mishna Berura's perspective or just saying that in general grandparents can say the blessing too just like parents?

Comment: Sounds like he is saying, assuming a person rules that the parents make a shechechayanu... The asker there didn't ask whether the grandparents should make a bracha at all.